# Loadable library and Perl binaries are mismatched

Tags: deepin, pac-manager

I cannot run `Pac-manager` after installing the `.deb` file. I downloaded Pac Manager from [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pacmanager/)

When running `pac` in the terminal, it's showing the below problem:

```
xs/Vte.c: loadable library and perl binaries are mismatched   
(got handshake key 0xdb00080, needed 0xdb80080)
```

System:

```
Linux PC-pc 4.4.0-3-deepin-amd64 #1 SMP Deepin 4.4.30-2 (2016-12-01) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Pac-Manager Stopped the development there is forked project call  Asbru .

https://github.com/asbru-cm/asbru-cm

https://www.asbru-cm.net/

which is exactly similar to pac-manager .